# Determine all integers x,y that satisfy the equation $x^3 = y^2 +2$

Tags: number-theory

Determine all integers x,y that satisfy the equation $x^3 = y^2 +2 $

My attempt to the solution

Taking mod 2 we get that x an y can't be even. How to proceed?
By trial and error there is a solution $y =\pm5$ and $x =3$.

Comment: Hope to wake up to somebody having written enough that I don't need to. The standard proof uses the fact that $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-2}]$ is a Euclidean domain. Then one factors $x^2+2$ as $(x+\sqrt{-2})(x+\sqrt{-2})$, and does some calculations. There must be a proof that mentions only ordinary integers, but I do not recall seeing one.

Comment: $x^3-3^3=y^2-5^2$

Comment: its different ..